# EXTRACT query in Vb.net using sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

*This is my code then the problem is it will not show the information in the gridlist. I want to make inner join of my two tables but it doesn't work with my codes. What will be the alternative way of this? Thank you so much for answering.*

```
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT Persons.pr_id, Persons.pr_fname, Persons.pr_mname, Persons.pr_lname, Persons.pr_address, Users.UserName, Users.phone_num FROM Persons" & _
                             "INNER JOIN Users ON Persons.pr_id = Users.pr_id" & _
                             " WHERE pr_id='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    Dim table As New DataTable
    cn.Close()
    cn.Open()
    With cmd
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .Connection = cn
    End With
    With cmd
        .CommandText = sqlQueryUser
        .Connection = cn
    End With

    With sqla
        .SelectCommand = cmd
        .Fill(table)
    End With

    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        'Button20.Visible = True
        'Button10.Visible = True
        'RichTextBox2.Enabled = False
        'senbyCombo.Enabled = False
        'group_sendCombo.Enabled = False
        'title.Enabled = False
        'ListView3.Enabled = True


        id = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text
        TextBox1.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
        TextBox2.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
        TextBox3.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
        TextBox4.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text
        TextBox5.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text
        TextBox7.Text = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(6).Text


    End If
    cn.Close()
```

Comment: Your question is about sql query. You should rather post information about your tables, your query and the final result you are trying to achieve. The rest of the vb code does not help to support you.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Sorry FeliceM.. Next Time I will follow your post.. :)

Comment: @Naveen: Yes.. The Error is it will not display the result in Gridlist. Maybe there is something error in my query. My Desired Result is I want to extract an information and consolidate the Two tables through a gridlist. What will be the query for displaying the data of two tables?

Comment: @RealJayzie Unless you give the exact error message and the line which produced the error, it is difficult to give any solution. Only one mistake which we could make out is ambiguous column, which is mentioned in the below answer by Al-3sli. Use try catch and try to debug the code.

Comment: @RealJayzie One more suggestion, try running the SQL in DBMS and check if it returns any record.

Answer (score 1):

your `pr_id` is `ambiguous` change your query like this :

```
Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT Persons.pr_id, Persons.pr_fname, Persons.pr_mname, Persons.pr_lname, Persons.pr_address, Users.UserName, Users.phone_num FROM Persons" & _
                         "INNER JOIN Users ON Persons.pr_id = Users.pr_id" & _
                         " WHERE Persons.pr_id='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
```